# How good do accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 have to be to use for flight critical environments?

Tags: precision-recall, f1

How good do accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 have to be to use for flight critical environments?

Maybe there are rules of thumb, general practices, best practices, lessons learned, etc.

Flight critical typically likes to see 10-9 for flight critical mishaps and occurrences, so is there an equivalency of the values for accuracy, precision, recall, and F1?

Is there something akin to confidence interval for the accuracy, precision, recall, and F1?  That way one could say with X confidence that accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 for a certain scenario/function/application?

Thanks a ton for any and all insights.

Comment: I think you intended to say $10^{-9}_{\,}$. The ICAO Manual of Civil Aviation Medicine sets out an arbitrary "one disaster in ten million flying hours" and within that suggests a risk of disaster due to pilot medical incapacitation of "one in a thousand million flying hours"

Comment: Please can you help narrowing down on what are you exactly trying to classify (with the mention of accuracy et al.) within the context of flight critical environments?

Comment: B Liu - the question is in general.  Is there guidance for how high the classification accuracy et al need to be for flight critical applications, but the same question would extend to life critical, safety critical, etc? Hoping the stats community has a rule of thumb, or generalized guidance some place.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Henry that is the intent but couldn't get fonts to cooperate.  Thanks.